# iOS device trouble in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

For some reason I cannot switch from an iOS device in Xcode.  It will not display an option to switch to an iPhone or any other device.  It just says iOS device and I cannot even run the iOS simulator and test the app.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: you have to download simulators

Comment: go to Preferences -> Downloads, and download desired simulator devices